# Select (Select field from FieldTable) from Table

Tags: sql-server, view

I'm using MSQL 2005. I have 2 table.A and B

### Table A

```
- ID DOVKOD
- 1  KURSATIS
```

### Table B

```
- ID KURALIS KURSATIS
- 1  2,2522  2,2685
- 2  2,4758  2,4874
```

Table A has only 1 record

When I execute `Select (Select DOVKOD from Table A) from Table B`     I want to get same result as   `Select KURSATIS from Table B`

I am gonna use it in a view. How can I do that. Thanks..

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Your query doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select columns from one table based on the column names from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702203/select-columns-from-one-table-based-on-the-column-names-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT DOVKOD FROM A) = 'KURSATIS' THEN KURSATIS
            ELSE KURALIS
       END     
FROM B
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ffa0/1)

Comment: @user2170349 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The only way how to do this in MySQL is using Prepared statements. [Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) is a good article about this.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
Select DOVKOD INTO @sql
FROM from Table A;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, 'FROM Table B');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: he can not put that into the view

Answer (score 0):

You must use Dynamic TSQL

```
SELECT @column=DOVKOD from Table A

EXEC ('Select ' + @column +  ' from Table B')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right then in table A you have the name of the column that you want to return. Then your solution is bad at all. I'll rather do something like that:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TableA
(
    ID INT, DOVKOD VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES (1, 'KURSATIS');
CREATE TABLE #TableB
(
    ID INT, Value DECIMAL (18,2),Name VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (1, 2.2522 , 'KURALIS');
INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES (2, 2.4758 , 'KURSATIS');

SELECT #TableB.* FROM #TableB JOIN  #TableA ON #TableA.DOVKOD = #TableB.Name
```

Comment: KURALIS, KURSATIS field name, not values. Anyway Thanks for advice.

Comment: I know that it is field name. What I want to say that you can not implement the view in the way you described. I just made suggestion that design itself is bad.