# Select columns from a table based on the column names from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I want to select data from following tables for a Jasper report.

**AA_COLUMN_NAMES**
[image]

**AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS**
[image]

**DDL + DML**

```
CREATE TABLE SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    active bit
);
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES (id, name, active) VALUES (1, 'col_1', 1);
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES (id, name, active) VALUES (2, 'col_2', 1);
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES (id, name, active) VALUES (3, 'col_3', 1);
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES (id, name, active) VALUES (4, 'col_4', 0);
CREATE TABLE SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username varchar(500),
    col_1 varchar(500),
    col_2 varchar(500),
    col_3 varchar(500),
    col_4 varchar(500)
);
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS (id, username, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) VALUES (1, 'chathura', '500', '200', '300', '0');
INSERT INTO SLPAYROLL_LIVE.dbo.AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS (id, username, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) VALUES (2, 'gihan', '300', '100', '100', '0');
```

I want to select only active columns from `AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS`. The active column names can be get from the `AA_COLUMN_NAMES` table.

I have googled my question and found the following solution.

[Select columns from one table based on the column names from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702203/select-columns-from-one-table-based-on-the-column-names-from-another-table)

Since I want to use that query in a Jasper Report, above solution does not worked. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: can someone explain why down-voted my question without answering or explaining a proper reason?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you or why. I've upvoted now that your question contains proper sample data. I don't know if I'll have the time today to post an answer, though.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you please post an answer when you have a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL to do this - here is one fairly simple way:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000) = '';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL +', '+ name 
FROM dbo.AA_COLUMN_NAMES
WHERE active = 1

SET @SQL = 'SELECT id, username' + @SQL + ' FROM dbo.AA_PAYMENT_DETAILS'

EXEC(@SQL)
```